# Add migration - Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a solution with multiple projects one of them with EF 6 and another one with entityframeworkcore.

The migrations were working fine before adding EF6 project, but now I can't use the migration's command : `add-migration 'anything'`

Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6.

For the project with EF6 I can add a migration using this way:
`EntityFramework\Add-Migration 'anthing_here'`, but I can't add a migrations to the project with EFCore using this way.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration anything`?

Comment: You can try with [dotnet core cli tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) . You should be able to run migrations from external command window by pointing to project folder...

Comment: you could try `dotnet ef add-migration`  if you get an error saying `dotnet-ef` isn't a command, then you're missing the tooling from your `.CSPROJ` file.

Comment: @AdamVincent I had exactly the same error 'dotnet-ef isn't a command' , but adding tools its throwing error : ''DotnetCliTool' is not supported by project' .

Comment: are you targeting a .net core app? You can use EF 6 in a .NET Core App, but you can't use EF Core in a .NET Framework app afaik

Comment: I have got this work around, Unloaded the project with EF6 then clean ,rebuild the whole solution and added migration, it gave me the same error but did migrate this time !

Answer (score 11):

I had this same scenario happen on our project that spans now ~20 years in history.

It has everything from **Web Forms**, to latest **.Net Core** technologies.
Depending on luck, I would sometimes get that `PackageManagerConsole` was using `EFCore` sometimes `EF6`.

I was not happy that I had to use prefixes like above answer stated so I dug deeper.

If you run command `Get-Module` in your `PM> PackageManagerConsole` you should get list of active modules:

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                                                
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                                
Script     6.4.4      EntityFramework6                    {Add-EFDefaultConnectionFactory, Add-EFProvider, Add-Migration, Enable-Migrations...}                                                                                                                           
Script     5.0.10     EntityFrameworkCore                 {Add-Migration, Drop-Database, Enable-Migrations, Get-DbContext...}                                                                                                                                             
Script     2.0.0.0    NuGet                               {Add-BindingRedirect, Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-Project...}                                                                                                                                                
Script     0.0        profile
```

Problem here is as you can see and probably even know that both `EntityFramework Core and 6` are being used by solution.

You can remove one of the modules that are conflicting, using command:

```
PM> Remove-Module <module-name-from-list>
```

What I needed was to **use only EFCore so I removed EF6 module** like so:

```
PM> Remove-Module EntityFramework6
```

And then you can use commands without prefixes, e.g.:

```
PM> Add-Migration TestMigration
```

*Relevant discussion I had with EF team:* https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27051

Comment: plus one for Get-Modules but when I remove EntityFramework6  and reopen visual studio it get back to the list

Comment: thanks to your answer . but when I reopen my vs I see this again . exactly like @sabsab

Comment: @HaydarDehghan I solved the problem... it was a nuget package that refrerences old ef 6

Answer (score 7):

For EF6:

```
EntityFramework\Add-Migration <MIGRATIONNAME>
```

For EF Core:

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration <MIGRATIONNAME>
```